# SELECT and TRUNCATE in Sybase stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sybase

I am trying to get all the data from a table and then clear all the data using a stored procedure. I tried the following:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE "RD1DTA"."my_procedure"()
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM rd1dta.qrtsp
    TRUNCATE TABLE rd1dta.qrtsp
END
```

This only does the SELECT but it doesn't do the TRUNCATE. If I do the TRUNCATE before the SELECT then it does the TRUNCATE but not the SELECT. How do I get it to do both?

I am using sybase to do this.

Comment: what will you do with the select? (what is the purpose)

Comment: It's being used by a 3rd party. The actual procedure looks more complex than this. They are sending me some IDs through AJAX request. I dump those IDs into a table. I use those IDs to display some data that they want (when they call this procedure). But then they want the procedure to also clear those IDs.

Comment: this approach is likely to case concurrency issues (more than 1 user it blows up), read this: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/08/15/temporary-tables-in-stored-procedures.aspx

Comment: What would you recommend? To get the IDs as a table input to the procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel,

Use a temp table:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE "RD1DTA"."my_procedure"()
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO #XYZ FROM rd1dta.qrtsp
    TRUNCATE TABLE rd1dta.qrtsp
    SELECT * FROM #XYZ
END
```

Hope that helps.

-Dave